# Access private object property

Tags: php, amf, sabre

I'm using SabreAMF to decode AMF data in PHP. I'm getting result as :

```
Rtmp\SabreAMF\AMF3\SabreAMF_AMF3_Wrapper Object
(
    [data:Rtmp\SabreAMF\AMF3\SabreAMF_AMF3_Wrapper:private] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => value1
        [1] => value2
      ...
```

The problem is that I can't access data property to get an Array with values because it's a private property. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea of private members is that they are blocked from being accessed from outside.

If you have access to the class, you can write a `__get` method which will help you (but if you have the access you can also make them public).

Some workaround is to "catch" the output of `print_r`, `var_export` or `var_dump` functions and then parse it, so you would get what you need.